# Creating ArcGIS 9.3 geodatabase in ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, esri-geodatabase

Dooes anyone know if it's possible to create a v9.3 geodatabase from ArcGIS 10?

Opening them is not a problem, but I haven't found a way to create one without going back to 9.3 and doing it there.

Comment: Voted to close as exact duplicate.